# Undo/Redo Menu Items not working with Document based app OSX 10.7

Tags: macos, cocoa, data-binding, undo, nsdocument

I've created a very simple test Document based application with Core Data.  I did no coding, just wired it up.  The XIB file has one array controller, one table view and two buttons, one to add a row and one to delete.  The array controller is binded the Files Owner's managedObjectContext.  The columns of the table are bound to the three entities defined in the model.  The buttons are wired to the array controllers Add and Remove actions.  That's it.  The application works fine, but the menu items for Undo and Redo stay disabled after you add or remove rows.  Is there something you have to do to enable undo/redo functionality at this level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here may be related to this:

> The columns of the table are bound to the three entities defined in the model.

I'm not even sure how you would do that (bind different columns to different entities.) I'm wondering if you mean "three properties defined on one entity in the model," but I'm not sure.

Regardless, I replicated something like your setup: a simple entity `Person` with one string property `name`, an NSArrayController, in entity mode, bound to the (File's Owner, , managedObjectContext), an NSTableView with one column, bound to (Array Controller, managedObjects, name) and everything works great, including Undo and Redo.

I'd recommend starting from that simple point (one entity, one property, one column, everything works) and adding complexity/features one little thing at a time until something breaks -- when it breaks, you'll know exactly what broke it. Luckily, you're starting from boilerplate, so there's not a lot of extra app logic getting in the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You are correct, I bound the columns to different properties of the same entity.  My issue was not setting the Array Controller to be in **Entity mode**.  Now my issue is trying to understand why my more complex app doesn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: So, going back to my more complicated example, I added `windowWillReturnUndoManager` to my `NSPersistentDocument` subclass, and it worked!!  This is interesting because a simple out of the box subclassed `NSPersistentDocument` works without this method.  Also interesting it seems that neither `NSDocument` or `NSPersistentDocument` adhere to the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol which defines `windowWillReturnUndoManager`.  So, the interesting question is how does this even work out of the box??

Comment: The ArrayController has access to the undoManager because you bound it to the managedObjectContext, which has access to it because it's owned by the NSDocument, which is the de-facto window delegate here. Also, while many Cocoa delegate interfaces are declared as protocols, my understanding is that the kit will take pretty much anything as a delegate, and will test it's implementation of certain methods by calling respondsToSelector: before actually trying to call the delegate method.  The protocols are there more as a hint to developers than as a strict type safety mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If a menu item is disabled, that means there is nothing in the responder chain that responds to the message it's sending.  In this case, it likely means that your window is not returning the undoManager.  You need to have something like this in your window controller:

```
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)sender
{
    return [self.managedObjectContext undoManager];
}
```